# Unix Run Command is not generating the log for R Script

Tags: r, bash, shell, unix, command-line

I am running two different commands to run two different R Scripts and one of it is generating log and other is not. I am unable to figure out why .. any pointers would be appreciated

Working and generating log/error

```
Rscript main.R '2021=Jun_2021.xlsx&2021=May_2021.xlsx' 2> output/test_err.txt | tee output/test_log.txt
```

Executes Script but Not generating log/error

```
Rscript main.R '2021=TESTFILE.xlsm&Param1=INZ01&param2=Test' 2> output/test_err.txt | tee output/test_log.txt
```

Comment: Other than the third arguments, there is no difference between the two commands, so it is impossible for us to know why one generates output and the other does not. (I'm assuming several validation steps such as: `output/` dir pre-exists; no file-perms problems; the `main.R` script runs to execution and does what it should in both examples. The last one is the biggest assumption, tbh, and likely to be the culprit.)

Comment: yeah both scripts do what they r supposed to do and rest of the code works like charm in both scripts. only issue being generation of log files. :|

Comment: Look at pre-conditions: is the file present or absent in both cases? It might be that it does not exist in one case (in which case it is created normally), but it does exist in the other and *not-clobbered*, meaning nothing done with it.

Comment: as per ur suggestion. tried cleaning everything from output folder before running both the scripts and also changed execution seq, still no same issue

Comment: If your `main.R` is not complex, it might be informative to add it to your question so that we can look for holes in your logic; lacking that, I hope somebody else thinks of a possibility, I think I'm out of ideas.

Comment: there is nothing wrong in what you posted, so it must be that the R script does not output anything under certain conditions.  Impossible to help further without more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as it turned out, i had a script to cleanup the output folder and was deleting these .txt files in the process.
Appreciate your inputs guys, thanks.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30171429)